# Do i need to delete the storyboard in order to create an interface programatically?

Tags: swift

Is it mandatory to delete the storyboard and it's reference from the plist in order to develop the interface of an app pure programatically or just making changes in app delegate file will be enough?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don’t have to delete the storyboard file, but you should. We should never keep legacy code/files floating in our projects.

If you haven’t already, though, I’d suggest putting the project under source control. Commit the version with the storyboard. Then, when you’re done with your programmatic conversion, remove the storyboard and any references to it, and then commit that. That way, you’ve got the old storyboard stored away in source control, but not cluttering your actual project.

Answer (score 0):

I found this guide: https://softauthor.com/ios-ui-design-programmatically-xcode-9-swift-4. It seems that deleting the storyboard is part of the process but I wouldn't doubt that you can simply just change the info.plist and the app delegate to ignore its presence without needing to delete it entirely.